# asp.net grid view bound field to text box

Tags: asp.net

I have a boundfield in a gridview. How can I change the boundfield to a textbox only for a specific column?

I tried

```
BoundField colname= new BoundField();
grid.Columns.Add(colname as TextBox);
```

But it goves a cast expression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work for your situation, but you could try using a template field, like this:

```
<asp:TemplateField>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%#Eval("SomeValue")%>' ... />
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

**EDIT**: Adding TextBox to item template from code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack) 
    {
        TemplateField txtColumn = new TemplateField();
        txtColumn.ItemTemplate = new TextColumn();
        GridView1.Columns.Add(txtColumn);
    }
}

public class TextColumn : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "MyTextBox";
        container.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**: Setting text of dynamically added TextBox

```
//get the cell and clear any existing controls
TableCell cell = e.Row.Cells[0];
cell.Controls.Clear();

//create a textbox and add it to the cell
TextBox txt = new TextBox(); 
txt.Text = cell.Text;    
cell.Controls.Add(txt);
```

Comment: nopes i dont do this in the mark up...I need the code behind way of doing it...I want to cast the BoundField to a text Box dynamically form the code behind

Comment: I don't know if you can do it with a bound field, but you might be able to add a textbox to a template field from the code behind. Let me check it out and I'll edit my answer.

Comment: I dont have template field...I have a bound field inside a grid view which is added to the grid view from code behind.Can you please modfiy my code snippet...im a bit confused...thanks

Comment: Can you not use a template field instead? I don't think you can add a TextBox to a bound field.

Comment: Hey thanks i found a way to do it The link is http://forums.asp.net/t/1660176.aspx/1

Comment: Okay... if that works for you. How are you planning to bind the value to that textbox?

Comment: this is the next problem i am facing...i am not getting the value...any idea??

Comment: Hehe... I saw that one coming. To reiterate again, I think a template field would be better if at all possible, but I will edit my answer with something you can try with your current approach.

Comment: I am getting this instead of the value System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCell

Comment: e.Row.Cells[colIndex].ToString();  isnt this same as your approach??

Comment: The example is wrong. You need to use `Cells[cellIndex].Text`, and you'll probably need to clear the text from the cell after setting the text in the TextBox.

Comment: Nope. My approach gets the Text property of the cell.