# ASP.NET Add TextBox to GridView

Tags: asp.net

I have an asp.net 4.5 web application and I'm trying to add a textbox in a gridview from C#. How can I do that? All the examples I found are about setting an ItemTemplate and adding a TextBox in it. That's not what I want.

So I have this:

```
<asp:GridView ID="InsertReportData" runat="server" Visible="False">
<Columns>
</Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

I have managed to add boundfield and itemtemplate with this:

```
BoundField bfield = new BoundField();
bfield.HeaderText = "Name";
bfield.DataField = "Name";
InsertReportData.Columns.Add(bfield);

TemplateField tfield = new TemplateField();
tfield.HeaderText = "Country";
InsertReportData.Columns.Add(tfield);
```

How can I add a textbox in this tfield? I should be able to it with:

```
tfield.ItemTemplate.InstantiateIn();//but when I tried adding a textbox here, it didn't work..can't compile..error.
```

Can this be done somehow?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [asp.net grid view bound field to text box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324718/asp-net-grid-view-bound-field-to-text-box)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer here for more [asp.net grid view bound field to text box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324718/asp-net-grid-view-bound-field-to-text-box)

create a new class by inheriting ITemplate like below

```
public class TextColumn : ITemplate
{
    public void InstantiateIn(System.Web.UI.Control container)
    {
        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = "MyTextBox";
        container.Controls.Add(txt);
    }
}
```

and use like below code when you want to add new text box

```
TemplateField txtColumn = new TemplateField();
txtColumn.ItemTemplate = new TextColumn();
GridView1.Columns.Add(txtColumn);
```

Comment: ??????? did you even read my post ?? Where did I say I want to add a textbox in a bound field ? I want to add a textbox to a gridview from C#. Not to have it in an ItemTemplate from the beginning.

Comment: have you checked this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7324718/asp-net-grid-view-bound-field-to-text-box

Comment: Have you read my post ? I don't want to add an ItemTemplate. I want to generate everything from C#.

Comment: YES ! I already implemented that class that inherited from ITemplate but my mystake was when I was doing txtColumn.ItemTemplate = new TextColumn(); //I was using new TextBox(). Thank you !